# Getting the following error: Permission denied (publickey) when trying to SSH

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, server, client

When I tried to use ssh to connect to the server with the following command:

```
ssh username@ipadress
```

but I get the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error? Do I need to enter the port? Because when I do that I get the following following error message:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Do you have `telnet` to the server? Try to run `telnet ipadress 22`.

Comment: Thank You! It worked! Now a follow-up question it hit anything after connection I get this `Protocol Mismatch` `Connection closed by foreign host.` What does this mean?

Comment: Did you use the RSA key for connecting to the server?